# Verificação login button Facebook no Android

Tags: android, facebook, login

Boa noite, sou novo na programação, estou começando agora.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte, comecei a estudar a API de Login do Facebook, ela está fazendo login normalmente e encaminhando para a próxima activity, até aqui tudo bem. O problema está quando fecho o aplicativo e abro novamente, ele inicia na primeira activity com o botão "sair", da própria API, depois de sair e fazer o login novamente ele me encaminha para a próxima activity. Teria como gravar o login, para quando o aplicativo fosse reiniciado ele verificasse se já estiver logado encaminhar para a segundo activity?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O botão "Sair" indica que você já esta logado, ao clicar em Sair você acaba deslogando do app e fazendo login novamente, o que você precisa fazer é verificar se o identificador dele é nulo ou não, caso não seja significa que já existe um usuário logado. Se ja estiver logado você sai da SplashActivity para a HomeAcitivy por exemplo. Caso não esteja logado você sai da SplashActivity para LoginActivity.

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
```

Não esquecer de iniciar o facebook sdk.

Comment: Então seria mais ou menos  dessa forma?
                        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, SegundaActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

Comment: exatamente  não precisando o user ter que sair e fazer login denovo

Comment: Opa deu certo, mas agora surgiu um outro problema... Antes de armazenar o token, o APP pegava a foto de perfil e o nome do usuário logo após o login, agora quando tenho o token armazenado ele abre na segunda activity sem fazer as requisições de foto e nome. Tenho que armazenar elas em cache? Mas penso eu que isso esta ocorrendo pq estou verificando o token no onCreate antes do app buscar as informações

Comment: Tente isso https://gist.github.com/jcaiqueoliveira/9ea00f70f32a945621d7